# How to serialize an object as JSON and write it to a pipe asynchronously in .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I want to asynchronously serialize a POCO object and write it to the response body without:

- Having to buffer the response myself.
- Going through an UTF-16 `string`.

Here is what I have now:

```cs
            await using var w = new Utf8JsonWriter(context.Response.BodyWriter);

            JsonSerializer.Serialize(w, rpcResult, serializationOptions);
```

The problem is that `JsonSerializer.Serialize` is not async.

`JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync` does not seem to have an overload that accepts `Utf8JsonWriter`. while `JsonSerializer.Serialize` does.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializeasync?view=netcore-3.1) from Microsoft, you can actually call `SerializeAsync` with `UTF8` stream object. Please check that.

Comment: Yes, but that method writes to a `PooledByteBufferWriter` that rents an Array from the ArrayPool and flushes to the stream, the `context.Response.Body` stream is a `HttpResponseStream` that wraps a `PipeWriter`. Why do that when you can write to the pipe directly. There is a sync method for this but it is missing it's async overload.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469794/c-net-core3-0-system-text-json-jsonserializer-serializeasync for more details about Async vs standard version.